# Conditional SQL statement - switching between insert/update query

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

Is there a way to insert if/else clause into the following line here:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE Table1 SET ID=value1,Team=value2 WHERE ID=value3";
```

In a case where **ID=value3** (in other words the row already exists) can be found then an update query takes place but where it cannot be found I want an insert query to take place:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (ID,Team) VALUES (value1,value2)";
```

to take place... how can I do that?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // save to access database when user clicks on the save button
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
    {
        //the file path of mdb
        string filepath = @"C:\Users\sy\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\demo\demo\CE_Database.mdb";
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" + filepath + ";";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = conn;
        //your update satemenet
        command.CommandText = "UPDATE Table1 SET ID=value1,Team=value2 WHERE ID=value3";
        conn.Open();
        //update to ms access
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know if the row exists or not? Do you query the database, so that you have the Id present at some point?

Comment: NB You don't have to explicitly close the connection within a `using` block.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: Really? Reference?

Comment: @methuselah - Have you checked out sqlservers MERGE?

Comment: Since MS Access does not support "upsert" check this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6200623/3098069

Comment: @dotNET I've just checked the IL for `OleDbConnection.Dispose`, and the `Close` method is called.

Comment: @ZevSpitz You are definitely right on this one. I have added the code behind `OleDbConnection.Dispose()` to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: Thanks a bunch. Never knew that. I have removed my comment. Does it happen for Streams/readers/writers too?

Comment: @dotNET Yes it does, [the online docs](http://www.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh40558e.aspx) state the Dispose method *"Closes the underlying stream, releases the unmanaged resources used by the StreamReader, and optionally releases the managed resources."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` will return the number of rows affected, you can check what this returns from the update command, if the record does not exist the method will return 0, then you can then progress to the insert method:

```
private string filepath = @"C:\Users\sy\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\demo\demo\CE_Database.mdb";
private string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" + filepath + ";";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    if (this.Update() == 0)
    {
        this.Insert();
    }
}

private int Update()
{   
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Table1 SET ID=value1,Team=value2 WHERE ID=value3", conn);
    {
        conn.Open();
        return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
private int Insert()
{       
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Table1 (ID,Team) VALUES (value1,value2)", conn);
    {
        conn.Open();
        return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

---

To clear up comments on the answer, the `OleDbConnection.Dispose()` method looks like this:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        this._userConnectionOptions = null;
        this._poolGroup = null;
        this.Close();
    }
    this.DisposeMe(disposing);
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

So the connection will be closed by the Dispose method, so there is no need to explicitly call `Close()` when your connection is in a using block

Comment: A better writeup than my answer :>

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're after the `MERGE` statement... which doesn't exist in the JET version of SQL. This'll work for most things though:

```
UPDATE Table1 RIGHT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.[KeyField] = Table2.[KeyField]
SET Table1.[KeyField] = Table2.[KeyField],
Table1.[OtherField] = Table2.[OtherField]
```

If it is in `Table2`, it will be inserted into `Table1`, overwriting the value (updating), if it's already in `Table1`.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Check for the existence of ID = 3 through a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query before running `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the UPDATE query first with ExecuteNonQuery(), which returns the number of affected rows.

If affected rows are 0, then you'll run your INSERT query.

```
            //the file path of mdb
            string filepath = @"C:\Users\sy\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\demo\demo\CE_Database.mdb";
            conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" + filepath + ";";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = conn;
            //your update satemenet
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE Table1 SET ID=value1,Team=value2 WHERE ID=value3;";
            conn.Open();
            //update to ms access
            int affectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // returns 1 if the row exist, 0 if it does not.

            if (affectedRows == 0)
            {
                  command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (ID,Team) VALUES (value1,value2)";
                  command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // perform insert
            }

            conn.Close()
```

EDIT: As Gord Thompson pointed out, the original solution did not work. ExecuteScalar() with "UPDATE .....; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT". Changed this to use ExecuteNonQuery, and get  the number of affected rows from that method.

Old solution using @@ROWCOUNT:

```
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE Table1 SET ID=value1,Team=value2 WHERE ID=value3; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;";
            conn.Open();
            //update to ms access
            int affectedRows = (int)command.ExecuteScalar(); // returns 1 if the row exist, 0 if it does not.

            if (affectedRows == 0)
            {
                  command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (ID,Team) VALUES (value1,value2)";
                  command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // perform insert
            }
```

Comment: Not good. I'll edit so that it use Executenonquery(), and remove @@rowcount. :)

Answer (score -1):

Use @@ROWCOUNT

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE Table1 SET ID=value1,Team=value2 WHERE ID=value3 IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 INSERT INTO Table1 (ID,Team) VALUES (value1,value2)"
```

Edit: As Gord said this won't work, I was too fast, didn't notice it's Access.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913258/if-rowcount-0-sql-syntax-error-in-access)  is a similar question and solution.

Comment: That won't work in Access.